# Why is my SVM not reaching good accuracy when trained to perform binary classification of search results?

Tags: ai-design, classification, support-vector-machine

I am trying to perform binary classification of search results based on the relevance to the query.
I followed this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-934a444fca47) on how to make an SVM, and I got it to work with a small iris dataset. Now, I am attempting to use the LETOR 4.0 MQ2007 dataset by Microsoft to classify. The dataset has 21 input vectors as well as a score from 0 to 2. I classified 0 as -1 and 1, 2 as 1. My algorithm reaches 57.4% accuracy after 1000 epochs with 500 samples of each classification. My learning rate is 0.0001. here is my code.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


print("-------------------------------------")
choice = input("Train or Test: ")
print("-------------------------------------")

# HYPERPARAMETERS
feature_num = 21
epochs = 1000
sample_size = 500
learning_rate = 0.0001

if choice == "Train":

    out_file = open('weights.txt', 'w')
    out_file.close()

    print("Serializing Train Data...")

    # SERIALIZE DATA
    file = open('train.txt')
    train_set = file.read().splitlines()
    positive = []
    negative = []

    # GRAB TRAINING SAMPLES
    for i in train_set:
        if (i[0] == '1' or i[0] == '2') and len(positive) < sample_size:
            positive.append(i)
        if (i[0] == '0') and len(negative) < sample_size:
            negative.append(i)

    train_set = positive+negative
    file.close()

    features = []
    query = []

    # CREATE TRAINING VECTORS
    alpha = np.full(feature_num, learning_rate)
    weights = np.zeros((len(train_set), feature_num))
    output = np.zeros((len(train_set), feature_num))
    score = np.zeros((len(train_set), feature_num))

    for i in tqdm(range(len(train_set))):
        elements = train_set[i].split(' ')
        if int(elements[0]) == 0:
            score[i] = [-1] * feature_num
        else:
            score[i] = [1] * feature_num

        query.append(int(elements[1].split(':')[1]))
        tmp = []
        for feature in elements[2:2+feature_num]:
            if feature.split(':')[1] == 'NULL':
                tmp.append(0.0)
            else:
                tmp.append(float(feature.split(':')[1]))
        features.append(tmp)

    features = np.asarray(features)

    print("-------------------------------------")
    print("Training Initialized...")

    # TRAIN MODEL
    for i in tqdm(range(epochs)):

        # FORWARD y = sum(wx)
        for sample in range(len(train_set)):
            output[sample] = weights[sample]*features[sample]
            output[sample] = np.full((feature_num), np.sum(output[sample]))

        # NORMALIZE NEGATIVE SIGNS
        output = output*score
        # UPDATE WEIGHTS
        count = 0
        for val in output:
            if(val[0] >= 1):
                cost = 0
                weights = weights - alpha * (2 * 1/epochs * weights)
            else:
                cost = 1 - val[0]
                # WEIGHTS = WEIGHTS + LEARNING RATE * [X] * [Y]
                weights = weights + alpha * (features[count] * score[count] - 2 * 1/epochs * weights)

            count += 1

    # EXPORT WEIGHTS
    out_file = open('weights.txt', 'a+')
    for i in weights[0]:
        out_file.write(str(i)+'\n')
    out_file.close()

elif choice == "Test":

    print("Serializing Test Data...")

    # SERIALIZE DATA
    file = open('train.txt')
    train_set = file.read().splitlines()
    positive = []
    negative = []
    for i in train_set:
        if (i[0] == '1' or i[0] == '2') and len(positive) < sample_size:
            positive.append(i)
        if (i[0] == '0') and len(negative) < sample_size:
            negative.append(i)

    test_set = positive+negative

    file = open('weights.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
    weights = np.zeros((len(test_set), feature_num))

    # CREATE TEST SET
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        weights[i] = file
    features = []
    query = []
    output = np.zeros((len(test_set), feature_num))
    score = np.zeros((len(test_set)))

    for i in tqdm(range(len(test_set))):
        elements = test_set[i].split(' ')
        if int(elements[0]) == 0:
            score[i] = -1
        else:
            score[i] = 1

        query.append(int(elements[1].split(':')[1]))
        tmp = []
        for feature in elements[2:2+feature_num]:
            if feature.split(':')[1] == 'NULL':
                tmp.append(0.0)
            else:
                tmp.append(float(feature.split(':')[1]))
        features.append(tmp)

    features = np.asarray(features)

    for sample in range(len(test_set)):
        output[sample] = weights[sample]*features[sample]
        output[sample] = np.full((feature_num), np.sum(output[sample]))

    predictions = []
    for val in output:
        if(val[0] > 1):
            predictions.append(1)
        else:
            predictions.append(-1)

    print("-------------------------------------")
    print("Predicting...")
    print("-------------------------------------")
    print("Prediction finished with "+str(accuracy_score(score, predictions)*100)+"% accuracy.")
```

My training algorithm

```
if(val[0] >= 1):
    cost = 0
    weights = weights - alpha * (2 * 1/epochs * weights)
else:
    cost = 1 - val[0]
    # WEIGHTS = WEIGHTS + LEARNING RATE * [X] * [Y]
    weights = weights + alpha * (features[count] * score[count] - 2 * 1/epochs * weights)
```

What could I do to help the model train? Am I not giving it enough time? Is the algorithm wrong? Are the hyperparameters ok?
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you clarify this part "I classified 0 as -1 and 1, 2 as 1"? Does it mean that the original datasets has 3 classes and you're joining two classes so that you can perform binary classification? Also, you have only a total of 1k training examples? That's a relatively small dataset.

Comment: Yes. The samples are scored 0 - 2, so I classified 0 as -1, and 1 and 2 as 1. Is this not a good way to do it? What would be an adequate sample size? Is my training algorithm ok?